# UnknownHostException causes Fatal error in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the following code, and all works fine when I can connect to the server:

```
  public void getXMLData()
    {
        if (skipUpdate)
        {
            skipUpdate=false;
            return;
        }
        skipUpdate=true;
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int SERVERPORT=0;
        try {
            SERVERPORT = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("pref_key_port_1","Port"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            txtStatus.setText("Invalid Port Number");
            return;
        }
        String SERVERHOST = prefs.getString("pref_key_host_1","127.0.0.1");
        String PASSWORD = prefs.getString("pref_key_pass_1", "password");
        try {
            XMLFetcherTask myXMLFetcherTask = new XMLFetcherTask(SERVERHOST,SERVERPORT,PASSWORD);
            myXMLFetcherTask.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            txtStatus.setText("Error "+e.getMessage());
            return;
        }


        skipUpdate=false;
    }


    public class XMLFetcherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response = "";
    String password="";

    XMLFetcherTask(String addr, int port, String pass){
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
        password=pass;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);


            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(password);

            response="";
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while (response.toLowerCase().indexOf("</response>")<0)
            {
                response+=input.readLine();
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           txtStatus.setText("UnknownHostException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            txtStatus.setText("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            txtStatus.setText("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally{
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    //txtStatus.setText("Exception Finally: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if( !(response.substring(0,5).equalsIgnoreCase("<resp") || response.substring(0,5).equalsIgnoreCase("<?xml")) ) //!response.substring(0,5).equalsIgnoreCase("<?xml") ||
        {
            txtStatus.setText("Server response doesn't look XML, please check password: '"+response.substring(0,5)+"'");
        } else {
            lastXMLData=response;
            txtStatus.setText("Resp Len: " + response.length());
            skipUpdate=false;
            updateFragmentListeners();
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Now, when I get UnknownHostException, the app force close with following stack trace:

```
07-29 15:52:08.754    1525-1538/android.process.acore V/BackupServiceBinder﹕ doBackup() invoked
07-29 15:52:08.766    1525-1538/android.process.acore E/DictionaryBackupAgent﹕ Couldn't read from the cursor
07-29 16:29:55.178    1525-1534/android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
07-29 16:29:55.178    1525-1534/android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
07-29 16:29:55.178    1525-1534/android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

I have no idea why this happen...
I tried to comment hte txtStatus.setText as normally it's not supposed to work from another thread, but no change.
Tested on android emulator with framework 22 and on my phone with framework 21.
Any idea would be welcome

Comment: You have to call close on your StreamWritter and reader

Comment: Since the exception is thrown while creating the socket, the input and output streams should not even be created.  I tried anyway this with no luck:
finally{
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    input.close();
                    out.close();
                }

Answer (score 0):

Ok I manage to make it work using threads instead, here's final code:

```
 public void getXMLData()
    {
        if (skipUpdate)
        {
            skipUpdate=false;
            return;
        }
        skipUpdate=true;
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int SERVERPORT=0;
        try {
            SERVERPORT = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("pref_key_port_1","Port"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            txtStatus.setText("Invalid Port Number");
            return;
        }
        String SERVERHOST = prefs.getString("pref_key_host_1","127.0.0.1");
        String PASSWORD = prefs.getString("pref_key_pass_1", "password");
        try {
           // XMLFetcherTask myXMLFetcherTask = new XMLFetcherTask(SERVERHOST,SERVERPORT,PASSWORD);
           // myXMLFetcherTask.execute();
            XMLFetcherTask XMLFetcherTaskThread = new XMLFetcherTask();
            XMLFetcherTaskThread.dstAddress=SERVERHOST;
            XMLFetcherTaskThread.dstPort=SERVERPORT;
            XMLFetcherTaskThread.password=PASSWORD;
            Thread cThread = new Thread(XMLFetcherTaskThread);
            cThread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            txtStatus.setText("Error "+e.getMessage());
            return;
        }


        skipUpdate=false;
    }

    public class XMLFetcherTask implements Runnable {
        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";
        String password="";

        private void setStatusFromThread(final String status)
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setStatus(status);
                }
            });

        }

        private void updateListenersThread()
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateFragmentListeners();
                }
            });

        }

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            //BufferedReader input = null;
            //PrintWriter out = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);


                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                out.println(password);

                response="";
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                while (response.toLowerCase().indexOf("</response>") < 0) {
                    response+=input.readLine();
                }
                if( !(response.substring(0,5).equalsIgnoreCase("<resp") || response.substring(0,5).equalsIgnoreCase("<?xml")) ) //!response.substring(0,5).equalsIgnoreCase("<?xml") ||
                {
                    setStatusFromThread("Server response doesn't look XML, please check password: '" + response.substring(0, 5) + "'");
                } else {
                    lastXMLData=response;
                    Date dNow = new Date( );
                    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss");
                    setStatusFromThread("Last update: " + ft.format(dNow));
                    skipUpdate=false;
                    updateListenersThread();
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                setStatusFromThread("UnknownHostException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                setStatusFromThread("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                setStatusFromThread("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            } finally{
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    //txtStatus.setText("Exception Finally: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }
            }

        }
    }
```